# Modifying property in codebehind doesn't update DataContext binding in ItemsTemplate of ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, datacontext

I made a test project to demonstrate my issue.
In the main window, I define a `ListBox` and its `ItemTemplate`, along with 1 button, *Update*.
In the `DataTemplate` I define a `CheckBox` with `IsChecked` bound to the `IsUsed` property.

```xml
<Window x:Class="Tests.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d">
    <WrapPanel>
        <ListBox x:Name="listBox">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsUsed}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
        <Button Content="Update" Click="ButtonUpdate_Click"/>
    </WrapPanel>
</Window>
```

Business object for items:

```cs
namespace Tests;

public class Foo
{
    public Foo(bool isUsed) => IsUsed = isUsed;

    public bool IsUsed { get; set; }

    public override string ToString() => IsUsed.ToString();
}
```

Code behind for MainWindow:

```cs
using System.Windows;

namespace Tests;

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        listBox.ItemsSource = new Foo[]
        {
            new(true),
            new(false),
        };
    }

    private void ButtonUpdate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Foo? SelectedItem = (Foo)listBox.SelectedItem;
        if (SelectedItem is not null)
        {
            SelectedItem.IsUsed = false;
        }
    }
}
```

The *Update* button inverts the boolean property `IsUsed` of the selected item.

Executing the program shows that the first item's checkbox is checked, as it should be.

**However, clicking on *Update* doesn't uncheck the checkbox even though it should, since it sets `IsUsed` property to `false`.**

I guess I need to modify the binding to fix the problem.

This problem isn't specific to booleans, I tested with other types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When change any property in behind, you need notify to UI this change for bind know.

```
 public class Foo : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        #region INotifyPropertyChanged implementos
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        #endregion

        private bool isUsed;
       
        public Foo(bool isUsed) => IsUsed = isUsed;

        public bool IsUsed { get => isUsed; set { isUsed = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); } }

        public override string ToString() => IsUsed.ToString();
    }
```

and change Checkbox bind to twoway if you need change by UI :)

```
  <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsUsed, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

sorry about my english :/